# required file not working but required file exist

Tags: php

I got some trouble, I made a dynamic requires function and i use it in two php file, in the same directory, called database_controller.php and Login.php. the fact is when i call the require function in the login file it says me after some test that the file exist but the require just after this test didn't take the file.
And on my file database_controller when i call the requires function it works without problems

the login file test for the require

```
require "./Utils/require.php";
if (file_exists(requires(intval($rows["role"])))) {
    echo "exist";
    require requires(intval($rows["role"]));
    echo "loaded";
    //doing something with the dynamic require
}
else {
    echo requires(intval($rows["role"]));
    exit;
}
```

when i run the login i got the error 500 internal server error and the response of the login file is only "exist"

here's th content of the ./Utils/require.php

```
/**
 * @function requires
 * @param $userType
 * @return int|string
 */
function requires($userType) {
    switch($userType) {
        case 0:
            if (file_exists("Path to required file for user type 0")) {
                return "Path to required file for user type 0";
            }
        else
            return 0;
        case 1:
            if (file_exists("Path to required file for user type 1")) {
                return "Path to required file for user type 1";
            }
            else
                return 0;
        case 2:
            if (file_exists("Path to required file for user type 2")) {
                return "Path to required file for user type 2";
            }
            else
                return 0;
    }
}
```

and here's the what i made on the database_controller with the same function

```
require_once "./Utils/require.php";
require_once "./error.php";
/*
 * Post request method for packers
 */
if ($UserType == 0) {
    if (requires($UserType)) {
        require requires($UserType);
        //doing something with the dynamic required file
    }
}
/*
 * Post request method for supervisors
 */
elseif ($UserType == 1) {
    if (requires($UserType)) {
        require requires($UserType);
        //doing something with the dynamic required file
    }
}
/*
 * Post request method for admins
 */
elseif ($UserType == 2) {
     if (requires($UserType)) {
         require requires($UserType);
        //doing something with the dynamic required file
    }
}
```

Here i didn't have the 500 internal server error, i have the 200 ok and i have specifics form displayed

Comment: here is the request header:
Host: easyweb.neyconsulting.ch
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 Iceweasel/38.5.0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://easyweb.neyconsulting.ch/
Content-Length: 46
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: and the response header:
Connection: close
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 09:35:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Comment: There is a semi colon `;` missing in line `echo "loaded"`. Also I need the error log of php.

Comment: Are you still getting 500 error?

Comment: yes and only the exit is displayed in the response

Comment: and i have test with hard coding of the path link instead of the dynamic requires and got the same response

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use autoloading?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGSerlMoIrY

Maybe you just need to define the absolute path to the project root.
Put this in a separated file and require it on your public index.php

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your_project_root' );
```

then in your public index.php just

```
require_once'../app/the_config_file.php';
```

now when you dynamically require something just do it like:

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . '/path_to_the_file.php';
```

Comment: i already test it to, i've maybe found where is the problem. I will post it further if i'm right

Comment: I solve the problem it was a conflict between two classes with the same name. on the login.php  i use an DBLogin class for the connection and on the required file in call the second indentation of DBLogin which is not the same class because of different access right to the database between both DBLogin

Comment: Ahh :D In case you want to have two classes with the same name, you can use namespaces. Here is the example: Imagine you have a folder named MP3 and inside you have 1000 songs. There is high chance that there will be name collisions. It is better to organize those 1000 songs into folders (by artist name). This way you can have songs with the same name, but under different directories. Namespaces are just like that. You specify namespace for that class. And when you want to use that class elsewhere, just add "use classname;". Check it out, it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem it was a conflict between two classes with the same name. on the login.php i use an DBLogin class for the connection and on the required file in call the second indentation of DBLogin which is not the same class because of different access right to the database between both DBLogin